# want to add image left corner of div

Tags: css, image, html, background

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.connection {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
width:50px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
color:#FFFFFF;
}


.ui-corner-all {
-moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
.ui-widget-content {
background:url("images/ui-bg_inset-soft_25_000000_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #000000;
border:1px solid #666666;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ui-widget {
font-family:Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:1.1em;
}
.con-text {
 font-size:0.7em;
  margin-top:-0.7em;
  padding:2px;


}
.conimage {
background:url("access-link-card.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.con-icon {
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
z-index:100;
 background: url("access-link-card.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 34px;
}
</style>
</head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="connection ui-draggable" id="connection-581" style="left: 435px; top: 123px;">    
    <div class="con-icon" id="con_icon-581">   
        <div class="con-text ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="con-text-581">        Rahul3      
        </div>    
    </div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want this image in the left corner of div con-text or con-icon as badge,
image is coming not full size please help how the image will come in full size

regards
rahul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it as a background image and add a padding to the element so that the text appears to the right of the image:

```
.con-text {
  font-size:0.7em;
  margin-top:-0.7em;
  padding:2px;
  background: url(your_image_url) no-repeat;
  padding-left: something-greater-than-image-width px;
}
```

Comment: hi i have changed code and edit in question now problem is that image is coming not full size please help how the image will come in full size

Comment: Set `width` and `height` for the div to be greater than image size.

Answer (score 2):

you could try Casablanca's answer, another option is to set the background position of the image:

```
.con-text {
    background url('yourImage.jpg') no-repeat 5px 2px;
}
```

when positioning background elements, the two pixel values are horizontal eg (5px) then vertical (2px).

Adjust with your browser's developer tool for the desired position.