# Menu icons in top left/right and bottom/left right corner

Tags: menu

I'm having trouble figuring out how to place four menu icons in each corner of a div. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you found during your research? I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903747/want-to-add-image-left-corner-of-div detailing how to place an image in the left corner of a div, do you think you could adapt it for the other corners? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903747/want-to-add-image-left-corner-of-div

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below to see how to setup this type of layout.  Then head over to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Y7F/19/) to see how it looks.  Basically, you want to use absolutely positioned elements (such as divs to hold your icons) within an element (your parent div) that is relatively positioned.  Doing that lets you explicitly specify where the child elements will be positioned within the parent.  You specify the top, left, right and bottom css properties for each element.

The first css class below says any DIV element with a class of outside should be styled with these settings.  The rest work the same way.

The CSS:

```
div.outside
{
    border: 1px solid black;     
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

div.topLeft
{
    border: 1px solid red;     
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

div.bottomRight
{
    border: 1px solid green;     
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

div.topRight
{
    border: 1px solid blue;     
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

div.bottomLeft
{
    border: 1px solid yellow;     
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

In the HTML below the DIV with a class of outside is the container.  The DIVs within would be where you would place your icons (where I have TL, BR, TR and BL).
The HTML:

```
<div class="outside">    
    <div class="topLeft">TL</div>
    <div class="bottomRight">BR</div>
    <div class="topRight">TR</div>
    <div class="bottomLeft">BL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that helped a lot. What if I want the icons to be fixed to the top and bottom corner of half the screen (I'm doing a split-screen layout)?

Comment: I assume you're building a navigation and content layout, side by side?  If so, I've updated the fiddle to show how you would build something like that.  The heights might look a little odd (178px) but they're done that way to take into account the 1px wide borders.

Comment: Are you sure you've updated the Fiddle? This looks like the old example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Y7F/19/

Comment: DOH!  Working on the train using my phone to tether my laptop.  I guess my connection dropped.  I'll update it again when I get to work.

Comment: Ok, updated the fiddle (correctly this time).  You can find it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/MikeDevenney/573bT/  The blue squares would be the menu icons.

Comment: If this does it for you, can you mark my answer as the answer to your question?  That adds to my SO rep (and makes me feel all warm and fuzzy!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't quite do it. Is it possible make the menu icons fixed to the corners within the div.nav?

Comment: They should be fixed to the corners.  If you have a working example posted on the web somewhere I can take a look, but the css does keep those divs fixed to the corners with a spacing of 5px.